# JDBC commit(): what happens behind the scenes?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, transactions

I'm helping with a deadlock hunt. The environment: Tomcat 5.5, Java 5, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, jTDS (replacing an old driver). We have a legacy connection pool.

The database code always follows this scheme:

```
connection = connectionPool.getConnection(); // 1
boolean previousAutoCommitStatus = connection.getAutoCommit(); // 2
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // 3

// ... use the connection ...
// execute prepared statement 4
// execute prepared statement 5
// execute prepared statement 6

connection.commit(); // 7
connection.setAutoCommit(previousAutoCommitStatus); // 8
connectionPool.releaseConnection(connection); // 9
```

While we hunt the bug (pardon: the software defect) I was wondering: how does the driver work? My guess: whatever I do between (3) and (7) is queued by the driver/the DBMS. Only when I `connection.commit()` the DBMS begins a new transaction, acquires every lock the operations need (I hope that it is smart enough to lock the smaller possible set of objects), executes the statements and releases the lock, thus closing the transaction.

Or is it that as soon as I execute a prepared statement the DBMS locks the table?

**EDIT**: What I want to understand is if "commit()" translates in a set of SQL statements beginning with "begin trans/lock table" and ending in "commit/unlock table" or if any Java `executeStatement()` acquires the lock immediately.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that that `setAutoCommit()` (at 3) shouldn't be a `setAutoCommit(false)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in inside details,
On connection.commit of a SQLServer JDBC implementation

Following command is issued

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

@@TRANCOUNT = 0 -- no open transaction
@@TRANCOUNT = 1 -- 1 open transaction
@@TRANCOUNT =10 -- 10 open transaction

On setting autocommit to false,

```
set implicit_transactions on
```

These are MS SQLServer specific commands.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this resource](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/26465) the transaction starts as soon as you call `setAutocommit(false);`

I think it might still be driver dependant but this will be typical. See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378931.aspx) which says the same.

```
//Switch to manual transaction mode by setting
//autocommit to false. Note that this starts the first 
//manual transaction.
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: In the linked resource DevX Pro says: "setAutoCommit(false) and commit() implicitly mark the start of a transaction" which is controversial, to say the least. What I want to understand is if "commit()" translates in a set of SQL statements beginning with "begin trans/lock table" and ending in "commit/unlock table" or if any Java executeStatements() acquires the lock.

Comment: Understand. I would say this is really driver-dependant but my guess would be that typically setAutocommit(false) starts a transaction (effectively in the DB) and when you execute prepared statement in Java code it will send it to the server immediatelly and therefor obtain the locks once you call the SQL statement in java. I would expect the driver to act as direct proxy.

Comment: The MSDN resource seems to be more clear in this and even more relevant since it referes directly to MSSQL ...

Comment: Ok... so if between (3) and (7) someone foolishly packs a lot of time-consuming operations the tables would remain locked and starvation may occur. This is a very disturbing thought. Re-writing the whole big ball of mud is now considerably more appealing... :-|

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Triggers "BEGIN TRAN" on DB Server and

```
connection.commit();
```

Would trigger "COMMIT TRAN"

If you want to prevent locks between these two statements, set connection's isolation level to "Read Uncommited". You will have to ensure that it is acceptable in this scenario.

```
setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
```

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* goes on depends entirely on the driver implementation, so you need to check the documentation for the driver you are using to get a definitive answer.

setAutoCommit(false) does not necessarily begin the transaction on the database, and the statements do not necessarily execute on the database or even acquire the locks when you call the execute function in your code, as you surmised. That being said, as far as I know, shared (read) locks are ordinarily acquired when the statement is executed; update locks, when commit is called. You may be hitting a conversion deadlock (which happens when multiple statements's read locks on a given object are waiting to be converted to write locks), I'd check if your update statements have nested selects in them that may lead to such a lock.

Comment: No such luck with jTDS docs... I could not find anything (maybe it's just me)